Citable source on convergence rate of 1D function approximation methods vs DOFs (FEM vs. RBF vs. Fourier Series vs. splines vs. taylor series ....)?
I would like to cite a source (book/paper) comparing the convergence rate of different approximation methods for 1d functions on an interval. I have a hard time finding anything that actually compares methods to approximate functions rather than noisy data and does this for more than 1 approach (for example FEM literature will only compare different basis functions but not show the error vs a Fourier Series with same number of DOFs). A metric for the error would be the square integral difference but other comparisons are also good. Ideally something that compares the convergence rate with the DOFs on some varied test functions would be cool.
It has to be a reasonably respectable source, I'm interested in the actual result but also need to cite it, if such a general comparison is no where to be found (how could this be) I will probably write something like this in the near future when I have some free time because its immensely helpful when designing a numerical method for some novel task and trying to select the best approach. Thanks in advance.

Scientific Computing Stack Exchange might be a good place to post this if it doesn't get any good answers

Sorry, what is "DOF" again?

I used DOF/DoF for degrees of freedom, which is a more universally applicable metric than for example discretization distance as some methods like spline often reduce the number of degrees of freedom through extra conditions like C1 continuity on cubic splines.
